# 2-Column Table - Get Column One Text to Stack Onto Column 2

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-tables

My CSS is intermediate, currently I'm better at working with existing CSS than developing from scratch. I know that tables are a pain when it comes to responsive design. However I'm wondering, at smaller breakpoints, is there a way to get the text in column one to stack on top of the text in column two, so it looks better (see screenshot). The page in question is here: http://jesseddy.com/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use vertical alignment. The vertical-align property sets the vertical alignment (like top, bottom, or middle) of the content in cell.
Try set like this

{
  vertical-align: text-top
}

More detail at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align?v=example